# Default queue for new delayed jobs using delayed_job_3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I am using multiple heroku servers that share the same DB. I would like to have each server only process delayed jobs for the server that created the delayed job entry.

For example:

Server A only processes queue "server_a"

Server A only processes queue "server_b"

etc...

This is accomplishable by using Delayed Job 3 (https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)

However, for this to work I would need to manually assign a queue name for each delayed job created, which can be a pain. (for example: object.delay(:queue => 'tracking').method)

Instead I would like to be able to assign a "default queue" for all new jobs. Ideally, I put something like this in a delayed_job_config.rb & it works:

DEFAULT_QUEUE_NAME = ENV['APP_NAME']

... the idea being that I do nothing to existing delayed jobs & they automatically get assigned a queue with the same name as the app server.

I am looking for suggestions on how to accomplish this -- or if you want to give it a stab, throw some code my way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

In `config/initializers/delayed_job.rb`

`` Delayed::Worker.default_queue_name = `hostname`.chomp ``